How to display accurate values in Prometheus/Grafana
I’m using Grafana with Prometheus to monitor some metrics (the metric are generated using open telemetry), I’m sending metrics at irregular intervals but if this interval is big, it results in some ‘fake points’ being created, where the last sent metric is repeated over a certain period until the next metric is received. You can see this behavior in the screenshot below. I am not interested in seeing these “fake points.” Is there a way to display only the actual values that were sent?
I expect to see only the metrics that were sent.
Grafana
Prometheus
Value of the the metric sent
here is how I'm creating the metrics:
from opentelemetry.sdk.resources import Resource
from opentelemetry import metrics
from opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.proto.grpc.metric_exporter import OTLPMetricExporter
from opentelemetry.sdk.metrics import MeterProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.metrics.export import PeriodicExportingMetricReader
from random import randint
import time

COLLECTOR_ENDPOINT = "http://otelcol:4317"

resource = Resource.create(
    {
        "deployment.environment": "dev"
    }
)

metric_reader = PeriodicExportingMetricReader(OTLPMetricExporter(endpoint=COLLECTOR_ENDPOINT, insecure=True))
provider = MeterProvider(metric_readers=[metric_reader], resource=resource)
metrics.set_meter_provider(provider)
meter = metrics.get_meter("python-otlp-test")

# Global variable to store the latest gauge value
latest_gauge_value = None

def observable_gauge_func(options):
    global latest_gauge_value
    if latest_gauge_value is not None:
        yield metrics.Observation(latest_gauge_value, {'label': 'simple_label'})
        latest_gauge_value = None  # Reset the value after yielding

gauge = meter.create_observable_gauge("test_gauge_otlp", [observable_gauge_func])


def send_gauge_metrics(metric_name='None', metric=None):
    global latest_gauge_value
    latest_gauge_value = int(metric) if metric is not None else None
    metric_reader.force_flush()
    print(f'Metric {metric_name}, value: {metric}, sent')

#here I'm just trying to simulate the metrics being sent 
for i in range(4):
    for y in range(6):
        rad_metric = randint(1, 20)
        send_gauge_metrics("test-gauge", rad_metric)
        time.sleep(10)
        if y % 2 == 0:
            send_gauge_metrics("test-gauge", 0)
        time.sleep(10)
    time.sleep(120)

I'm running Prometheus and Grafana with docker composer and here is how the Prometheus is configured:
# Configure Prometheus to scrape the OpenTelemetry collector endpoint
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "otel-collector"
    scrape_interval: 1s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["otelcol:8889"]


What you call fake points is a result of staleness handling.

Cross post: https://community.grafana.com/t/filter-out-the-interpolated-data-points/124597
